# Subset list of data.frames with a numeric vector based on a logical condition

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

Here an example of my list:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10))
df2 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,11))

lst = list(df1, df2)

lst = lapply(lst, function(z) {z$id = seq.int(nrow(z)); return(z)})
```

Now I need to subset each data.frame based on a logical condition, i.e. I want to obtain two data.frames with `id` > 8 for df1 and `id` > 12 for df2.

```
num_vec = c(8, 12)
```

Here my expected result:

```
> lst
[[1]]
   a id
   5  9
   6 10
   6 11
   7 12
   8 13
   9 14
   9 15
  10 16

[[2]]
  a id
  9 13
  9 14
 10 15
 10 16
 11 17
```

With a single data.frame the syntax would be:

```
df1$id = seq.int(nrow(df1))
df2$id = seq.int(nrow(df2))

df1_sub = subset(df1, id > 8)
df2_sub = subset(df2, id > 12)
```

Thanks

Comment: One option with `tidyverse` `lst %>% map2(num_vec, ~ .x[.x$id > .y,])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
Map(f=function(x, y) x[ x$id > y,], lst, num_vec)
```

Map is a simple wrapper to mapply,  hence the function will be applied to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
lapply(seq_along(num_vec), function(i) lst[[i]][lst[[i]]$id > num_vec[i],])
#[[1]]
#    a id
#9   5  9
#10  6 10
#11  6 11
#12  7 12
#13  8 13
#14  9 14
#15  9 15
#16 10 16

#[[2]]
#    a id
#13  9 13
#14  9 14
#15 10 15
#16 10 16
#17 11 17
```